# Change dropdown menu side from right to left

Tags: html, css

Here is the navigation bar

[image: 1]

Now i want to change the side to this

[image: 2]

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-color: #E2DCDC;
}
nav {
  width: 994px;
  background-color: #77BCF1;
  border: 3px solid white;
  margin: 45px auto;
  color: black;
}
nav > .navigationbar_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
}
nav > .navigationbar_header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigationbar_li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigationbar_li_left {
  border-right: 3px solid white;
}
.navigationbar_li_right {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 3px solid white;
}
.navigationbar_li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.navigationbar_li > .navigationbar_a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.navigationbar_li > .navigationbar_a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.dropdown_ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown_ul > .dropdown_li {
  background-color: #77BCF1;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
.dropdown_ul > .dropdown_li > .dropdown_a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.dropdown_ul > .dropdown_li > .dropdown_a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.navigationbar_li:hover .dropdown_ul {
  display: block;
}
.float_left {
  float: left;
}
.float_right {
  float: right;
}
.clear_both {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navigationbar_ul">
    <div class="float_left">
      <li class="navigationbar_li navigationbar_li_left"><a class="navigationbar_a" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigationbar_li navigationbar_li_left"><a class="navigationbar_a" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="float_right">
      <li class="navigationbar_li navigationbar_li_right"><a class="navigationbar_a" href="#">Link 3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown_ul">
          <li class="dropdown_li"><a class="dropdown_a">Link 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_both"></div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cdeLznL/1/)**

**How can i do this?**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: next time remember to include at-least some code in the question description even if you are using and external link to your souse code (like jsFiddle). That external link may get broken over time and the question will become useless to those who see it later on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Might want to add some code to your post there! Makes it easier for us to help you out.

Regardless. I modified your css for the drop down on the right nav only. I changed the position of the `.navigationbar_li_right` to `position: relative;` and change the child, `.dropdown_ul` to `position: absolute;` **set the right value to 0, `right: 0;`**

**Update:** Modified based on jaunt's comment.

```css
.navigationbar_li_right {
  position: relative;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 3px solid white;
}
.navigationbar_li_right .dropdown_ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/5cdeLznL/3/)

Comment: This only works if it's the given width, I presume it will change width so I suggest editing `left:-24px` to `right:0px` to get the same result. :)